# datos de texview pasar a coordenadas android

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-v3, searchview, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

como hacer para pasar los datos de  texview  a coordenadas, en mi  programacion tengo lo siguiente

```
txtorigenlat1
 txtorigenlong1
```

para pasar esos datos a coordendas uso el siguiente codigo

```
double lat=Double.parseDouble(txtorigenlat1.getText().toString());
double lng=Double.parseDouble(txtorigenlong1.getText().toString());
request.setLocation(new Coordinate(lat,lng));
```

pero no funciona, se cierra automaticamente la app, si pongo directamente:
`request.setLocation(new Coordinate(-11.985647, -76.805545))`
; si funciona . ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo te recomiendo que cambies la palabra Coordinate por LatLng asi como te lo copio mas abajo

```
double lat=Double.parseDouble(txtorigenlat1.getText().toString());
double lng=Double.parseDouble(txtorigenlong1.getText().toString());
request.setLocation(new LatLng(lat,lng));
```

Comment: Lo que pasa para huawei la opcion del  buscador cercano se tiene que enviar las coordenadas
(https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-nearby-place--search-0000001050158585)

(https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/api-nearbysearchrequest-0000001050154749-V5)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo mismo amigo fui a donde me enviastes pero esos valores tienes que convertirlos a coordenadas latitud y latitud.. asi

```
    private void nearbySearch() {
        NearbySearchRequest request = new NearbySearchRequest();

        String locationLatitude = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.nearby_search_location_lat_input)).getText().toString();
        String locationLongitude =
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.nearby_search_location_lng_input)).getText().toString();
        Double lat;
        Double lng;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(locationLatitude) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationLongitude)) {
            if ((lat = Utils.parseDouble(locationLatitude)) == null
                || (lng = Utils.parseDouble(locationLongitude)) == null) {
                showFailResult("Location is invalid!", "", "");
                return;
            }
            request.setLocation(new Coordinate(lat, lng));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede convertir un valor de tipo doble en longitud y latitud a través de un objeto LatLng.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Los parámetros en el objeto son latitud y longitud de tipo doble. Puede usar Latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude) para construir un objeto LatLng. El objeto se puede aplicar para agregar marcadores en un mapa, por ejemplo:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker

El objeto también se puede aplicar para mover la cámara en un mapa a través del método newLatLngZoom(LatLng latlng, float zoom).
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#zoomBy(float,%20android.graphics.Point)

En su lugar, puede usar HUAWEI Map Kit. Se utiliza igual que Google Maps, excepto las dependencias en el archivo build.gradle a nivel de aplicaciones. Para obtener más información, visite el sitio web oficial:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-MapKit

Para obtener más información acerca del uso de LatLng, acceda al siguiente enlace:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/latlng-0000001050150800-V5